# Glassfish 4 with EMF Texo - JPA No persistence provider

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, glassfish, glassfish-4

I'm trying to use [EMF Texo](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Texo) in Glassfish 4, but when I want to initialize EntityManagerProvider I get the error:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named HelloTexo

I tried to implement the Texo tutorial found [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0oO4gw-gLI). The difference is that I want it to run on Glassfish 4.

Bellow is my code:

**web.xml:**

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>texo.web.TexoContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>emFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.emf.texo.server.store.CurrentEntityManagerRequestFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>emFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**TexoContextListener.java**

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import org.eclipse.emf.texo.server.service.ServiceModelPackageRegistry;
import org.eclipse.emf.texo.server.store.EntityManagerProvider;
import org.eclipse.emf.texo.test.model.base.identifiable.IdentifiableModelPackage;

public class TexoContextListener implements ServletContextListener{

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    ServiceModelPackageRegistry.getInstance().register(IdentifiableModelPackage.INSTANCE);
    EntityManagerProvider.getInstance().setPersistenceUnitName("HelloTexo"); 
    // initialize aggressively
    EntityManagerProvider.getInstance().initialize();
}
@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

In debug I get the error mentioned above when I try to initialize() the EntityManagerProvider.

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="HelloTexo" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider> 
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/__MySQLDataSource</jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I created this file automatically by adding JPA Project Facet to my project from Eclipse. The connection to database is succesful. I tried to move the persistence.xml to WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/ but I still get the same error.

Any idea what might cause the error? 
I am stuck here for some days now... I really hope someone will be able to give me an ideea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a classloader conflict. Glassfish4 includes EclipseLink in the container library path. Try removing your explicit `<provider>` tag and any jpa implementation jars from `WEB-INF/lib` folder. The standard Glassfish `javax.persistence.jar` should be all you need.

Comment: Thanks! Your remark regarding the classloader conflict solved the problem. I removed all jpa implementations jars from WEB-INF/lib and commented the <provider> tag. For those who have problems with Texo... I also removed from Glassfish all texo jars and just kept them in my WEB-INF/lib folder.